# setting static variable from properties file java

Tags: java

I need to use set some global variables which would be used by a few classes.

i'm having trouble assigning static variables from a properties files.

How i want to call the variables is something like this: String url = WebdriverConfiguration.getBaseUrl();

```
public class WebDriverConfiguration
{
    private static Properties testProperties;
    private static String instaceUrl;

    testProperties = loadProperties();


    public static final String DEFAULT_BASEURL = testProperties.getProperty("confluence.base.url","");
    private static final int DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT = 8080;
    private static final String DEFAULT_CONTEXT_PATH = "/";
    public static final String TEST_SPACE_KEY = "SMOKE";
    public static final String TEST_PAGE = "XXX";

    private static final String BASE_URL = System.getProperty("baseurl", DEFAULT_BASEURL);


    public static String getBaseUrl()
    {
      return BASE_URL;

    }



    private Properties loadProperties() throws IOException
{
    InputStream testPropertiesInput = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("webtester.properties");
    Properties testProperties = new Properties();

    if (null != testPropertiesInput)
    {
        try
        {
            testProperties.load(testPropertiesInput);
        }
        finally
        {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(testPropertiesInput);
        }
    }
    return testProperties;
}


   }
```

Comment: want assign static variables from that property file, see how there's some static variables, i would like to get some from the properties. The loading is fine, just not able to instantiate it from another class.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you're asking here, but the code you provided should not compile. Replace

```
private static Properties testProperties;
testProperties = loadProperties();
```

with

```
private static final Properties testProperties = loadProperties();
```

Update, found annother bug. You must change the method signature of `loadProperties` as well:

```
private static final Properties loadProperties() throws IOException {...}

           ^     ^
```

Comment: loadProperties needs to be `static` as well can can not throw a checked exception

Comment: @Tim Bender: just realized that as well - see my update.

Comment: throws error on getClass() says not static method

Comment: Replace getClass() with WebDriverConfiguration.class

Comment: 1 simply best. finally found the exact answer

Answer (score 1):

Using the current design in the question, the following changes would need to be made:

```
public class WebDriverConfiguration {
    private static Properties testProperties = loadProperties();
    //...snip...

    private static Properties loadProperties() { //must be static and can not throw a checked exception
    //...snip...
    }
}
```

Comment: would that enable me to call it from another class?

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoud do this :

First,make your constructor signature  to private.
Second,put your loadProperties() to static block.
Third,you should put all your properties to private.